# XHR error on first mobile call is failing, subsequent calls are all successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a vue js app that uses axios to open a new tab.  Below is the code.

```
var win = window.open('')
  win.document.body.innerHTML = Constants.LOADING_HTML
  axios.get('/api/inventory/report?vehicleId=' + id, {
  }).then(reporthtml => {
    win.document.body.innerHTML = reporthtml.data
  }).catch(error => {
    win.document.body.innerHTML = error.response.data
    win.document.title = 'Error'
  })
```

The call works perfectly fine when testing on my computer.  However, when testing on an iphone or ipad the first request that gets made throws an error.  After closing the opened tab and then making the call again it works correctly, and all subsequent calls work as well.

When debugging through safari I see the following error in the console when that call fails.  The first options call looks to return correctly.  But the get fails with no response message or a response code.  When looking at the api log, the call looks to succeed and return the appropriate data.

[image]

It looks like the catch is getting hit but not because of the api since error.response is empty.  When examining just error, it says Network error.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?  I have also tried disabling the popup block on ios with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: I see a `Protocol Error`, it could have something to do with `http` or `https`

Comment: Double checked all my calls they are all https.  And it only fails the first time, works the second time.

Comment: I've confirmed this looks to be an IOS only issue. Andriod doesn't look to have this issue.

Comment: Okay. This is something weird.

Comment: After further investigation it looks like my web api configuration is the issue.  After pointing my axios call to the dummy api https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 the error goes away on ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. The call I was making to the api had an async http call which was returning after the api call was complete. Looks like ios doesn't like that. After making the http call sync the error was resolved.